# VK_TAB is not working in SendInput() in my c++ Programe

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on one project where I am sending Paste command to another application window using `SendInput()` As Follows:

```
`INPUT input, vButton, ctrl1, ctrl2;` 
input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
input.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL; 
input.ki.wScan = 0; 
input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE ; 
input.ki.time = 0; 
input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

vButton .type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
vButton .ki.wVk = 0x56; 
vButton .ki.wScan =0; 
vButton .ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE ; 
vButton .ki.time = 0; 
vButton .ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

ctrl1.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
ctrl1.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL; 
ctrl1.ki.wScan = 0;
ctrl1.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP |KEYEVENTF_UNICODE ; 
ctrl1.ki.time = 0; 
ctrl1.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

ctrl2.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
ctrl2.ki.wVk = VK_TAB;
ctrl2.ki.wScan = 0; 
ctrl2.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ; 
ctrl2.ki.time = 0; 
ctrl2.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

// Send Input To Another Window
::ShowWindow(mainHwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
int retval = SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT)); 
retval = SendInput(1, &vButton, sizeof(INPUT)); 
retval = SendInput(1, &ctrl1, sizeof(INPUT)); 
retval = SendInput(1, &ctrl2, sizeof(INPUT));`
```

It is working fine except `INPUT` having `VK_TAB` key. I want Send `VK_TAB` command to the  application.

But it is not Working as Expected i.e. The next control is not getting focused even after successful completion of the `SendInput()`.

Can anyone help me on this.
How I can focus on next control of other application?

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: You set focus to a different control on a dialog by sending a [`WM_NEXTDLGCTL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645432.aspx) message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` for `dwFlags` if you are just sending simple keys. Set `dwFlags` to 0 for the KeyDown transition, and set it to `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` for the KeyUp transition.

You forgot to `SendInput` a KeyUp transition for `V` and a KeyDown transition for `VK_TAB`

Use that kind of code.

```
INPUT input:
input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input.ki.time = 0;
input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
input.ki.wScan = 0; 
input.ki.dwFlags = 0;

// Ctrl Down
input.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof( INPUT ) );
// V Down
input.ki.wVk = 0x56;
SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof( INPUT ) );
// V Up
input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof( INPUT ) );
// Ctrl Up
input.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof( INPUT ) );
// Tab Down 
input.ki.wVk = VK_TAB;
input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof( INPUT ) );
// Tab Up
input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof( INPUT ) );
```