# How to send a key using winapi's SendInput?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I am trying to convert [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19802769/831850) to Rust 1.3 with winapi-rs 0.2.4.

I have:

```
fn send_key_event(vk: u16, flags: u32) {
    let mut input = winapi::INPUT {
        type_: winapi::INPUT_KEYBOARD,
        union_: winapi::KEYBDINPUT {
            wVk: vk,
            wScan: 0,
            dwFlags: flags,
            time: 0,
            dwExtraInfo: 0,
        }
    };
    unsafe {
        user32::SendInput(1, &mut input, mem::size_of::<winapi::INPUT>() as i32);
    }
}
```

which does not compile with:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `winapi::winuser::MOUSEINPUT`,
    found `winapi::winuser::KEYBDINPUT`
(expected struct `winapi::winuser::MOUSEINPUT`,
    found struct `winapi::winuser::KEYBDINPUT`) [E0308]
```

Haw do I send keystrokes to the active window?

Comment: The correct way to automate a UI is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). What you are trying is a brittle hack. It will fail if the designated receiver is not the foreground window, for example. As an aside, the active window is of no relevance. Input goes to the foreground window. The foreground window happens to be the active window of the foreground thread.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the link! Do you have an example for rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `winapi::INPUT` in the version of winapi-rs you use is incorrect. [It appears to have been fixed today](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/commit/c492982d38592544f6e66cd3278c760b79741367) (or yesterday, depending on where you are).

Comment: so when the next version comes out, what code will get this to work?

Comment: The clearest way would be to zero-initialize the `u` member, then use the `ki_mut` method to get a mutable reference to a `winapi::KEYBDINPUT`, then assign to it: `let mut input = winapi::INPUT { type_: winapi::INPUT_KEYBOARD, u: Default::default() }; *input.ki_mut() = winapi::KEYBDINPUT { ... };`