# Passing a string into SendInput() (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sendinput

**Due To The Inconvenience, I've moved to C# for this project, no further comments needed**

I've encountered an issue during the development of a C++ tidbit, which sends keystrokes based on user input.

Upon trying to send the actual keystrokes, I am greeted with an error.

```
<error-type> message
```

I have posted a code snippet down below. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
/*Code snippet from program that handles actual keypresses*/
string message;
getline(cin, message);

SendInput(message);
```

Comment: @FredLarson Thank you for the answer, but I get another error in return. In this case, "too few arguments in function call"

Comment: You'll need to read [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx). It's not that simple, I'm afraid.

Comment: The error literally says "<error-type> message" ?

Comment: @immibis Indeed.

Comment: Is that a compiler error or is it what gets displayed when you mouse over message?

Comment: Way up there with the classic "Syntax error on line 42"

Answer (score 4):

Look at documentation for [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)

You have to setup the `INPUT` structure, then pass array of `INPUT`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::wstring msg = L"ΨΦΩ, ελη, ABC, abc, 123";
    //or std::string msg = "ABCD - abcd - 1234";

    std::vector<INPUT> vec;
    for(auto ch : msg)
    {
        INPUT input = { 0 };
        input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
        input.ki.wScan = ch;
        vec.push_back(input);

        input.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        vec.push_back(input);
    }

    //Find a notepad window or another window for send
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow("Notepad", 0);
    if (hwnd)
        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    else
        std::cout << "no window!\n";

    SendInput(vec.size(), vec.data(), sizeof(INPUT));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that ANSI is deprecated in Windows. This code with `std::string` works only for ASCII characters. For UNICODE compatibility use `std::wstring`

Comment: Note that `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` expects UTF-16 input, and separate `INPUT` down/up pairs for UTF-16 surrogate pairs. If you need to send non-ASCII strings, you need to convert them to this format.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I got ASCII and ANSI confused again. I think the answer is corrected now.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I now get the following errors: "'input' was not declared in this scope' and 'ch' does not name a type"

Comment: @Koi are you using C++11 or later? If not, then change the [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) into a normal `for` loop: `for(size_t i = 0; i < msg.size(); ++i) { ... input.ki.wScan = (WORD) msg[i]; ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [SendInput() Keyboard letters C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021175/sendinput-keyboard-letters-c-c)

You can't really just pass a entire string to it.

Comment: That's correct but the examples send one `INPUT` at a time, it's supposed to send an array.